# Avoiding pointers in std::list

Tags: c++, list, std

I try to avoid having pointers, and instead of doing

```
std::list<std::pair<int,int>* > myList;
void addElement(int a, int b) {
    myList.push_back(new std::pair<int,int>(a,b));
}
```

I figured i could do something like

```
std::list<std::pair<int,int> > myList;
void addElement(int a, int b) { 
    std::pair<int,int> p(a,b);
    myList.push_back(p);
}
```

If i understand the behaviour correctly, this should store a copy of the pair, and automatically delete it when doing `myList.clear()` (as opposed to the pointers).

Is this the best way to do it?
Can i expect the compiler to optimize away the unnecessary object `p`?

Comment: Does it matter if it is optimized away or not (the cost will be insignificant).

Comment: You are adding an item onto a list, which will cause a heap allocation, and will cause numerous cache misses on every iteration of the list -- and you're worried about copying two ints?

Comment: I'm worried about dealing with pointers in my code, and causing memory leaks. I asked to get some more experienced input on the implementation to make sure I wasn't doing anything exceptionally stupid.. I appreciate all the comments and replies.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> "Can i expect the compiler to optimize away the unnecessary object p?"

Maybe, maybe not.  Try this though:

```
myList.push_back(std::make_pair(a,b));
```

You usually have better chances of optimization when you work with r-values where applicable.

But even if it's not optimized away, that is no reason to resort to using pointers, especially for such small objects(not that I would advocate using pointers for large objects).  Only use pointers when they are semantically the correct thing to use, and that is rare.

Answer (score 5):

In C++0x, you could use `std::list::emplace_back`, which uses perfect forwarding to pass arguments to the object constructor, thus creating the `std::pair` in-place. But otherwise no; it'll need to create a temporary.

Answer (score 1):

It is unreasonnable to expect the copy to be optimized out. It might be, but it is somewhat doubtful.

The main issue is that an argument of a function must be fully evaluated before the function is called, so while for the case of a pair of ints, it might indeed work (it can be inlined, so the compiler may see there is no exception/side effet), it is in general plain unreasonnable.

On the other hand, given the high cost of a dynamic memory allocation, the copy is *bound* to be cheaper in this particular case anyway!